# How to insert a empty string to foreign key in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a Test table in gorm that looks like this:

```
type Test struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID      string `gorm:"index"`
    TradeID     string                    // another table foreign key
    Description string
}
```

And I'm trying to insert a data with a empty trade from **frontend form**:

```golang
// front json, trade_id is empty
{
  "user_id":"user-1",
  "trade_id":"",
  "description":"test"
}
```

This fails because the Test structs defaults the string value of the key to "" so the insert fails at the db level because `foreign key constraint fails`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a string pointer (`*string`) as the type, which defaults to `nil`. This way the insert won't fail if the field is nullable.

```golang
type Test struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID      string `gorm:"index"`
    TradeID     *string                    // another table foreign key
    Description string
}
```